# Alter session statement with case

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

In order to recompile a schema in an SQL*PLUS script either with or without debug information I have the following code:

```
define debug_compile = true

alter session set plsql_optimize_level = case when &&debug_compile = true then 1 else 2 end;
alter session set plsql_debug = &&debug_compile;
exec dbms_utility.compile_schema(schema => 'MYSCHEMA');
```

It seems that the `case` statement is not allowed with the `alter session` command.
Beside the obvious way of introducing another variable - is there an alternative to set the optimize level based on the variable `debug_compile`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit messy but you *could* use dynamic SQL:

```
define debug_compile = true

alter session set plsql_debug = &&debug_compile;
begin
  execute immediate 'alter session set plsql_optimize_level = '
    || case when &&debug_compile then 1 else 2 end;
end;
/

exec dbms_utility.compile_schema(schema => 'MYSCHEMA');
```

The `= true` is a bit redundant so I removed that.